# Regex find by pattern and replace only a part

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to write a regex expression that will seek for this pattern: `asdf=123` and then once something is found in a file/string, it should just replace the `123` part to `bbbcccddd`.

How can I do that in C# ?

Comment: Might this link help? : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: More details please. What is after/before "asdf=123" in your string / file? If it's something like "asdasd____ asdf=123_____asdasd" it's one thing but if it's " zzzzzzasdf=12309656097"  - is something different. It'd be nice if you provide shortened example of this string. Values are fixed  ?  Or it's just an example of pattern you're looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("11asdf=123 ttt", @"(?<=asdf=)123", "321"));
```

Though I write this code,but I think there will many problem because you don't describe your problem clearly,like if there some character not white before `asdf`,or there is some number after `123`,do you still want to replace `123`?

Answer (score 1):

```
string pattern = @"asdf=123";
var result = Regex.Replace(yourString, pattern, "asdf=bbbcccddd");
```

Comment: For such approach regex is overkill, just string.Replace will be enough https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like so:

```
string pattern = "asdf=123";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(.*?=)(.*)");
Match m = r.Match(pattern);
if(m.Success)            
      Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value + new String(m.Groups[2].Value.Reverse().ToArray()));
```

The above will match anything till it finds an equals (`(.*?=)`) and places it in a group. It will then match what follows and places it in another group (`(.*)`). The first group is then printed as is while the content of the second group is reversed.

A less verbose but less flexible way of doing this would be to use `Regex.Replace`, with something like so:

```
   string pattern = "asdf=123";
   Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(pattern, @"(.*?=)(\d)(\d)(\d)", "$1$4$3$2"));
```

This is less robust though since you would need to know the amount of digits before hand.

EDIT: As per your edit:

You will need to use: `Regex.Replace("asdf=123", "(.*?=)\d{3}","$1bbbcccddd")`

Comment: I do not need to reverse.. any string could be in there

Comment: @devhedgehog: I've updated my answer. Even though your edit changes your question completely.

Comment: The `.*?` part scares me in a large and arbitrary string of words. `(\S*=)` might be better.